# Use voting for "very low quality."

Tags: discussion, voting

This site has a lot of answers flagged for "low quality." But those answers are typically just very lazily answered or poorly sourced.

Please **use the *voting* features** to rank these questions as "not useful" 
— and don't forget to leave thoughtful *comments* to help the author (and **others**) understand how their answers can be improved.

[**Vote Early, Vote Often**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

Flagging posts is for egregious problems. Flagging posts into non-existence is reserved for misuse of the feature or in cases where the answer itself is actively harmful. Flagging these posts does not help users become better contributors, and requesting posts to be removed from the system for "low quality" is only going to drive users away.

Don't use the dark, private  back rooms of "flagging" as a substitute for proper voting, vetting, and on-going improvement of content.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Robert

Comment: I love how people backlash against this with comments like "stop downvoting!"

Comment: Is this still relevant?  The flagging dialog doesn't seem to include the "Low Quality" option anymore.