# What does each flag reason mean, and when should I use them?

Tags: discussion, flagging

What does each flag reason mean, and when should I use them?
I'm ready to dive in and help the moderators weed out content which requires their attention. What does each flag mean and when is the best time to use it?

Comment: I prefer if you put the link only. to benefit from the future edits to the original post in case there are new flagging reasons or any update..

Answer (score 1):

## Not an answer

The not an answer flag can only be associated to answers themselves (and not questions). Flagging criteria differs from scenario to scenario but the end goal is almost always post removal. Keep this in mind when flagging.

Use this flag when one of the following criteria is met:

- An answer is blatantly wrong and potentially harmful or dangerous to run.
- The answer is actually a comment which needs to be moved to the appropriate post
- The answer is instead another question which needs to become it's own separate post
- Instead of editing a post, someone has posted an edit as an answer and it needs to be merged in to another post instead

If an answer is just a "poor" answer (not very detailed, little perceived value, or you feel the urge to flag as not an answer when it does not fit the above criteria) then you should down-vote that answer instead of flagging it.

While some corner cases may exist that aren't covered above, those are the majority of cases that fall under this flag.

Comment: Another case could be a "poor answer" case where the answerer is unwilling to make any changes to his/her answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Very low quality

This answers content is not understandable or translatable, it can't be saved with editing or offers little to no solution at all.

This flag is designed to be used not because a post is "bad", but because it can not be saved at all. As a rule of thumb, if you flag a post because it *needs* to be edited, you should be editing it instead of flagging it.

This close reason also overlaps [Not an answer](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/254/119) in that if a post has no real solution (no real solution as it does not offer any support or solutions, not necessarily that the solution isn't optimal or a solution isn't exactly what the author is looking for) then it might as well be flagged as very low quality.

[It's highly recommended to leave a comment in this case to ask for improvement instead of flagging.](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/use-voting-for-very-low-quality)

Comment: It's highly recommended to leave a comment in this case to ask for improvement instead of flagging.

Comment: @Gigili ,This is a community wiki post , feel free to edit :-)

Answer (score 1):

## It is spam

This flag reason is pretty straight forward, with a few caveats. Spam is pretty easy to spot. Obviously purchasing Lucky brand jeans will not answer your questions about Ubuntu, if you see one of these posts use this flag reason instead of the "not an answer" flag reason.

The only caveat is with self-promotion. Self-promotion is allowed on the site *to an extent*. First the post must identify this is a solution they've created or work for, secondly they need to provide more than just a link (that is, either an abridged version of the solution, or a brief explanation of how to apply the software to fix the question asker's situation).