# Why do people of this site vote so less?

Tags: discussion, voting

First five pages, I saw very less questions with even 1 vote. Why isn't this community actively voting?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the issue is about the community not essentially voting per se.
The issue comes with the lack of good questions. Normally, when visiting the stack exchange, there are many personal issues users are facing trying to seek an answer to their panicked, distressed situations. Sometimes those questions aren't all like that. Some of them are duplicates, some of them aren't necessary duplicates but are similar in a way.
For example: "Is it a sin if I do xyz?" or "I've done xyz. Am I sinful?"
Questions like these can branch off into many different categories varying with different things people are unsure of whether is sinful or not. It doesn't even have to regard sinning, I'm just giving a brief example.

---

However, the issue is, those questions are more personal. Unlike questions that aren't more so personal but rather envelop the main faith itself, asking a question that many people themselves haven't thought about asking, now that's something that would peak many people's interests; specifically if the question itself is well researched, structured, and formulated.

---

The masses of questions on Islam Stack Exchange are more so personal, rather than well-written/researched/structured hence why they aren't as upvoted as much because many people don't find any reason to vote on a question that either doesn't concern them as much, doesn't make much sense to them, pique their interest, or even consider a good question in the first place.

Comment: If that's the case, perhaps a change of on-topic policy should be considered. I notice that the corresponding Christianity site explicitly excludes questions like
"*advice on how to handle certain situations*" and
"*open-ended is "X" a sin questions, asking whether a certain action or belief is sinful*",
and the home page begins with "*Like any library, C.SE offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your [religious advisor]*".

Comment: @RayButterworth I'm wondering why the site doesn't have that to be honest. They specifically refuse questions pertaining to dream interpretation, but nothing much else from my observations. The site itself has become somewhat of an "advice hub" rather than an Islam Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole bunch of reasons, here some of them:

- Many people don't care for the question quality, but about some specific part of the content -> in most cases exposed or described sin and sect (See for example [Don't make assumptions about the beliefs of any user by just reading the post they author](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/dont-make-assumptions-about-the-beliefs-of-any-user-by-just-reading-the-post-th/1658#1658)).
- Many questions show little or no prior research effort.
- Many people come up with personal issues. They look of a kind of fast fatwa. This is the kind of people who think, well this is too dump to bother a scholar with let's ask it here.
- Many people ask private questions (fatwas) for which they need a prompt answer. This hardly is achievable it is not what stack exchange is intended for.
- Many people ask variations of already asked questions, we try to close them by creating reference questions. (See for example: [Topics to which some reference questions could be useful](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/topics-to-which-some-reference-questions-could-be-useful))
- Many questions clearly are in conflict with the stack exchange policy: (See for example [(Islamic) counseling and agony-aunt](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/islamic-counseling-and-agony-aunt))

So most of these question hardly really fit in the stack exchange policy in a way or other.

See also:
[Please vote based on quality](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/please-vote-based-on-quality)
[Use voting for "very low quality."](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38/use-voting-for-very-low-quality)